# How to vertical scroll down in web browser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scroll, webbrowser-control

How can I scroll down the scroll bar in `WebBrowser` component in c#?
I tried the following code , but it doesn't did the job:

```
webBrowser2.Focus();
webBrowser2.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

To scroll to a specific location, you can use [`WebBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(x,y)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e8xf2s3(v=vs.110).aspx) method. For example to scroll down to the end of body:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
                                           WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, webBrowser1.Document.Window.Size.Height);
}
```

To scroll to a specific element, you can use [`ScrollIntoView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollintoview(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: To the anonymous user who asked: **Q:** *Hey can you please clarify what is that WebBrowser1 in your code because I am getting a erro when copying that code?*  **A:** It's a [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d(v=vs.110).aspx) which you put on the form.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{            
    webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height);           
}
```

So it became even more correct to work