# How to scroll down page in WebBrowser Control in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I need to scroll down web page (Facebook group members - http://www.fb.com/groupId/members) loaded in WebBrowser(wpf Control) to the height of loaded page (till possible).  As Suggested in Question (asked at `StackOver`) I'm trying to use JavaScript to get height and then to scroll to that. I'm using this code but not sure how to append my JavaScript method to call, Here is my Code

```
private void ScrollDownPage()
{
    mshtml.HTMLDocument dom = browser1.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
    IHTMLElementCollection scriptEl = 
    dom.getElementsByTagName("script");
    foreach(IHTMLElement i in scriptEl)
    {
        i.
    }


}
```

If there is another approach to this, please tell me.
Suggested Question ([How to vertical scroll down in web browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493681/how-to-vertical-scroll-down-in-web-browser-control)) Does not solve my problem as I have no `.Window.ScrollTo(X,Y)` available (I think this works for `WindowForms` but I'm using `wpf`

Comment: That Questions refers to WindowForms In my case (wpf) there is no .Window.ScrollTo(X,Y) available

Comment: I replaced it with a better dupe

Comment: Hope that works , but I've already tried many of such tricks